# Right way to partially update all items in an array with items from another array in redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In Redux, what's the best practice to update all items in an array with items from another array only with the fields that are common to the 2 arrays.

So for example :

```
billArrayInStore = [{id, amount, dueDate, summary}, ...] 
newBillArray = [{id, amount, dueDate}, ...]
```

Update each bill (amount, dueDate) but keep the 'summary' field untouched.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
newBillArray = billArrayInStore.map(bill => ({
  ...bill,
  amount: 0, // new amount
  dueDate: '', // new dueDate
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

For each bill object in `billArrayInStore`, you want to see if there is a corresponding bill object in `newBillArray` by comparing IDs. If you find a matching bill object, you then merge the two bills together into a new object. These new bill objects are stored in a new array to avoid mutating the original.

Since this solution involves transforming existing bill objects and storing them in a new array, it's a perfect use case for `Array.prototype.map`.

```
const updatedBills = billArrayInStore.map(bill => {
    // For each existing bill, check to see if there is a corresponding
    // new bill by comparing bill IDs.
    const newBill = newBillArray.find(newBill => newBill.id === bill.id);

    // If there is a new bill, merge the bills together using spread syntax.
    if (newBill) {
        // Order matters here, you want to spread the new bill last so it
        // can override any properties in the current bill. If the current
        // bill has properties that don't exist in the new bill, they won't
        // be changed.
        return { ...bill, ...newBill };
    }

    // If there isn't a corresponding new bill, the current bill should be
    // returned unmodified.
    return bill;
});
```

Here's a snippet with a working example.

```js
const billArrayInStore = [
  { id: 1, amount: 1000, summary: 'Rent' },
  { id: 2, amount: 50,   summary: 'Internet' },
  { id: 3, amount: 110,  summary: 'Electric' }
];

const newBillArray = [
  { id: 2, amount: 40 },
  { id: 3, amount: 125 }
];

const updatedBills = billArrayInStore.map(bill => {
  const newBill = newBillArray.find(newBill => newBill.id === bill.id);
  if (newBill) {
    return { ...bill, ...newBill };
  }
  return bill;
});

console.log(updatedBills);
```